# iOS Facebook SDK Invite selected user

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-invite-friends

I am trying to find a way to send app invite to selected users.
I can use 'App Invites' with App Link URL, but this does not allow setting of selected users before the dialog appears.

FBSDKGraphRequestContent does not have an action type of INVITE. So not able to use that.

I already got the list of invitable friends using invite_friends. How can I now use these user tokens to send app invite to selected users.

Comment: How to invite users are explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: This link says that I need Facebook Canvas. My app is an iOS app, so do I still need to setup Facebook canvas?

Comment: Also the link mentions that Game Requests dialog is needed to send invites to selected user. On iOS, as I mentioned in the question, FBSDKGraphRequestContent does not have an action type of INVITE. So the message just goes out as a normal game request if not action type is set.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot preselect users for App Invites.

The invitable_friends API is only for Game Requests.